# Toggle not working when clicking elsewhere

Tags: jquery

I have a link that when clicked will toggle two divs that show on/off states. That works fine using the following.

The problem I have is when another link is clicked, it remains in that state - so when the link is clicked it shows as on, when a link elsewhere is clicked it need to show as off.

How is that possible?

```
    $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.closer', this).toggle();
        $('.opener', this).toggle();

    });
```

For some context:

```
<li>
    <a class="toggle dot-link-<?php echo $count; ?>" data-number="<?php echo $count; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);"><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?>
        <span class="opener">+</span><span class="closer">-</span>
    </a>
    <span class="inner">
        <?php the_sub_field('content'); ?>
    </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Which state means they are open?

Comment: @Taplar `closer` (should've made that clearer!). It hides `opener` and shows `closer`.

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please.

Comment: Is the closer/opener class on the toggle element, or is it a child element?

Comment: @Taplar They're child elements, I'll post the code now

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //close all the others open, that don't belong to this toggle
    $('.toggle').not(this).find('.closer').removeClass('closer').addClass('opener');

    //toggle this one
    $('.closer', this).toggle();
    $('.opener', this).toggle();
});
```